# How to find out the number of solutions of a complex equation in second and third quadrant?

Tags: complex-numbers

> Consider the equation $ z^{2018} = 2018^{2018} + i$. How many solutions lie in the first quadrant?
> How many solutions lie in the second quadrant?

I get that there are $2018$ solutions and there'd be around $504-505$ solutions quadrant-wise but how to figure out the exact number?

Comment: If $\alpha$ is one solution, and $\zeta = \exp \frac{2\pi i}{2018}$, then the solutions are $\alpha\cdot \zeta^k$, $0 \leqslant k < 2018$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The points representing solutions are uniformly situated on a circle centered at $0.$ It suffices to work with the angles of the solutions:
$$\alpha_k=\frac{2k\pi}{2018}, k=1,\dots ,2018.$$
To find the number of solutions in the second quadrant, solve for $k$
$$\frac{1}{2}<\frac{2k}{2018}<1.$$